# Centering inside div thats both centered in a div and bigger and its parent depends on document width

Tags: css

I have a div inside a div, the child both being centered in its parent and bigger than the parent making it overflow equally on both sides of it. The child has another div inside it with some text.

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="text">
            testing testing
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.outer
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: beige;
    margin: 0 auto;

}

.inner
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin: auto;
}

.text
{
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: auto;
   width: 400px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/msVVD/4/

Now, if the document width is narrowed by resizing the browser window, or in the jsfiddle case, resized by dragging the handle between "JavaScript" and "Result", the text will not stay on the same horizontal position, but "travel" to the right.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a min-width to the body (or parent container in which the absolutely positioned element is aligned according to) like so

```
body
{
    min-width: 600px;
}
```

This will prevent the absolutely positioned from traveling

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/msVVD/8/)**

Comment: Set as solution for the simplicity

Answer (score 1):

You are not positioning the `.inner` element relatively to the `.outer` one.  Add `position: relative` to `.outer`.

Changes in your CSS:

```
.outer
{
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: beige;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.inner
{
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    background: pink;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;right:0;
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: -100px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/msVVD/7/

Comment: That will make the inner div not stay centered but grow to the right.

Comment: Changed `width: 600px;` to `500px` for `.inner`. It does not grow to the right when resizing the window. Forgot to adjust that when I added `padding-left: 100px`. Apologies if I did not understand your issue in the first place.